# firebase appengine: FirebaseUI buttons not showing up

Tags: python, firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I followed the tutorial (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/authenticating-users-firebase-appengine) for adding Firebase to a Google App Engine project. However, the UI buttons are not showing up; someone on Youtube did the tutorial for Node.JS and the UI buttons worked. This is what I see after following the guide:
[image]

It says Sign in, but nothing shows.

HTML

```
index.html
<!doctype html>
<!--
Copyright 2016 Google Inc. All rights reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
-->
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.6.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.4.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.4.1/firebaseui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="/main.js"></script>
  <title>Firenotes</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logged-out">
    <h1>Firenotes</h1>
    <h3>Sign in to access your notebook</h3>
    <div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="logged-in">
    <h1>Welcome, <span id="user"></span>!</h1>
    <h3>Enter a note and save it to your personal notebook</h3>
  <div id="form">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <textarea id="note-content"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <button id="add-note">Save note</button>
        <button id="sign-out">Sign out</button> 
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div id="notes-container"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

suscessful rediredt
    good.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample FirebaseUI App</title>
   <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDy38mpi5a_XI3BwZmxcaGG6AYfTp27yUM",
    authDomain: "proj-noah-f1280.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://proj-noah-f1280.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "proj-noah-f1280",
    storageBucket: "proj-noah-f1280.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "584810873981",
    appId: "1:584810873981:web:dc5305b0c20276f8bc9d14",
    measurementId: "G-2CQTJ3ZHHV"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      initApp = function() {
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
          if (user) {
            // User is signed in.
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var email = user.email;
            var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var phoneNumber = user.phoneNumber;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            user.getIdToken().then(function(accessToken) {
              document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed in';
              document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign out';
              document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = JSON.stringify({
                displayName: displayName,
                email: email,
                emailVerified: emailVerified,
                phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
                photoURL: photoURL,
                uid: uid,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                providerData: providerData
              }, null, '  ');
            });
          } else {
            // User is signed out.
            document.getElementById('sign-in-status').textContent = 'Signed out';
            document.getElementById('sign-in').textContent = 'Sign in';
            document.getElementById('account-details').textContent = 'null';
          }
        }, function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      };

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        initApp();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
    <div id="sign-in-status"></div>
    <div id="sign-in"></div>
    <pre id="account-details"></pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a reason why the buttons are not showing up?

Comment: You are already signed in. Click on the `Sign out` button. The example isn't that great IMHO - too tied for the notes app, changes are needed to make it work in a more generic manner.

Comment: @VickTree did the suggestion provided by Dan Cornilescu worked?

Comment: yes, it was resolved. If he writes an answer, i i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding @DanCornilescu's comment as answer as it solved the issue:

You are already signed in. Click on the Sign out button. The example isn't that great IMHO - too tied for the notes app, changes are needed to make it work in a more generic manner.